How to evaluate EL expression in Tomcat servlet environment?
How to evaluate EL expression in Tomcat servlet?
Tomcat uses Jasper EL.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper-el
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/el/package-summary.html
From the javadoc, it does not have ExpressionFactory impl to construct an ELContext object.
ELContext elContext = new ELContextImpl(expressionFactoryImpl);

Any examples on how to evaluate EL in Tomcat servlet?

Why? That's useful in a Web page where you don't have Java, but you do have Java in a servlet environment. There's nothing in EL that you can't evaluate directly in Java.

The first link is for tomcat-jasper-el artifact which has a dependency on tomcat-el-api. This EL API can be used for evaluating EL expressions in Java servlets:

EL in Stand-alone environment
EL 3.0 includes APIs for using EL in a stand-alone environment.
ELProcessor provides simple APIs for the direct evaluations of expressions. It also makes it easy to define functions, set variables, and define a beans locally.
ELManager provides a lower level APIs for managing the EL parsing and evaluation environment. It contains a default ELContext StandardELContext.

The examples you are looking is using old version of javax.el.

The answer of Roman is technically correct but most probably not the approach that you had in mind. The ELProcessor approach will only create a completely separate EL context where the JSP implicit objects and request/session/application attributes are not available and you have to manually manage these yourself in less or more the same way as shown in the second part of this answer: How to programmatically evaluate EL in a managed bean.
In order to be able to evaluate EL in a servlet which yields exactly the same results as if you were in a JSP page, then you need to create a ValueExpression with help of the ExpressionFactory as available by JspApplicationContext#getExpressionFActory() and the ELContext as available by JspContext#getELContext(). Here's a kickoff example:
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    JspFactory jspFactory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = jspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = jspFactory.getPageContext(this, request, response, null, false, 0, false).getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "${param.foo}", Object.class);
    Object value = valueExpression.getValue(elContext);
    // ...
}

In this kickoff example, the value variable represents the evaluated value of ${param.foo} which you can control by ?foo=bar query string.
As to the pom.xml configuration, you do absolutely not need Tomcat-specific dependencies. Just stick to standard API dependencies. It will then work just in any Servlet 2.1 compatible container. In case you're unsure which standard API dependencies to pick for Tomcat, head to this answer: How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?
